# Line equation - parametric and canonical

Tags: analytic-geometry

Let's say I have a line in R3:

$$
l:\begin{cases}
x-3y+3z=0\\
x+2y-2z=2
\end{cases}
$$
How to change it to canonical and parametric equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a parametric equation, add an equation:
$$ax+by+cz=t$$
Where $t$ is your parameter and $a$, $b$, $c$ are such that the system of three equations is regular. Here it's enough to let $t=y$.
Then solve for $x$, $y$, $z$ and you get them as functions of $t$.

Notice that with $t=x$, the system is not regular, since after removing $x$ from the first two equations, you get a system in $y$ and $z$ with null dterminant.

What do you call a canonical equation of the line ?

Comment: canonical (random example): x/2 = y+2/3 = z/1

Comment: Ah, ok. You find this by isolating $t$ from the parametric equations.